# Is it critical to use special paint for a corrugated asbestos roof?

Tags: painting, asbestos

My house has a small lean-to shed, which is about 4ft square. It has a corrugated asbestos roof. I'm planning on gently cleaning it with a fungicidal wash and then painting it.

There are products online for painting asbestos roofs but they are expensive and have a much greater coverage than I need for such a small job. I was thinking of buying a rattle can such as Hammerite or Rustoleum and painting with that - this way I'll not need to touch the asbestos. Is there anything special about asbestos paint or would one of these products do? Obviously, I want to avoid the situation where it all starts flaking off as I will not be able to scrub it down after!

Comment: That's a large area for spray paint. You'll probably use more than you realize and not end up with a uniform coat. I'd buy a quart of any good quality exterior paint and roll or brush it on. I see no reason to use special paint, nor to worry about "touching" the roof. Asbestos isn't phosgene gas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous brands of paint made for painting asbestos and you really need to use one on them. Just shop around and look for smaller quantities. These paints encapsulate the roof with a seamless coating, hence the long drying time, 10 to 12 hours. Normal rattle cans won't do that. Don't take shortcuts with this. Also, if it's such a small area, think about removing the roof and replacing it. Then you'll never have to worry about it.

Comment: I agree with removal, however, it can be _stupid_ expensive, even for a small area. I believe that in some places in the US a homeowner is allowed to remove small quantities himself (so long as it's properly bagged labeled & disposed of), but the OP is in the UK and regulations may be different there.

Comment: I can see a hermetic seal being important inside, but not on a roof. After all, the _underside_ is still unsealed.